# Find the more similar items with weighted datas

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x

I have a lot of dictionaries containing the weighted tags for each artist of my music library and I would like to find the more similar artists (perhaps with a similarity rating too?), given a dictionary of weighted tags.

For instance:

```
tags = {
    'grails': {
        'post-rock': 100,
        'instrumental': 53,
        'experimental': 38,
        'ambient': 30,
        'post rock': 14,
        'psychedelic': 11,
        'Psychedelic Rock': 6,
        'Progressive rock': 6,
        'rock': 4,
        'instrumental rock': 3,
        'atmospheric': 3,
        'american': 3,
        'space rock': 1
    },
    'camel': {
        'Progressive rock': 100,
        'classic rock': 28,
        'art rock': 24,
        'Progressive': 18,
        'rock': 17,
        'symphonic prog': 7,
        'british': 6,
        'Symphonic Rock': 4,
        'Canterbury Scene': 3,
        'prog rock': 3,
        'prog': 3,
        'Psychedelic Rock': 2,
        'space rock': 1
    },
    'mozart': {
        'Classical': 100,
        'mozart': 30,
        'instrumental': 21,
        'composers': 16,
        'opera': 13,
        'piano': 11,
        'Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart': 9,
        'symphonic': 9,
        'orchestral': 8,
        'austrian': 5
    }
    # etc.
}


best_matches({
            'Progressive rock': 100,
            'experimental': 33,
            'classic rock': 26,
            'Progressive': 23,
            'rock': 23,
            'art rock': 12,
            'psychedelic': 5,
            'prog rock': 5,
            'british': 5,
            'prog': 4,
            'Experimental Rock': 3,
            'Avant-Garde': 3,
            'Psychedelic Rock': 3,
            'Jazz Rock': 2
        }, tags)

# should output camel, then grails, then mozart
```

I heard about some recommendation algorithms such as Slope One but I was wondering if there's an easier way to do this kind of calculations with Python, and what would be the fastest algorithm to "compare" all these dictionaries.

Comment: What do you mean by "weight"?

Comment: The weight of each tag is the second value of the dictionaries. For example, if its 100 or a big value, it means that the tag perfectly describes the artist and should be considered as more important than the others during the comparison. Sorry, I don't know if I make myself clear.

Comment: Your artists don't all have the same tags. You need to think how to deal with missing tags: is it the same as a tag with weight 0, or some other fixed value, or should the number of common tags have some positive effect on the computed similarity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) or Euclidean distance if you regard each genre of music as a dimension in a vector space. Cosine similarity is particularly easy, it's just the L2-normalized dot product:

```
def intersect(a, b):
    """Intersection of a and b."""
    return (k for k in a if k in b)

def dot(a, b):
    """Dot product of values in a and b."""
    return sum((a[k] * b[k]) for k in intersect(a, b))

def l2norm(a):
    """L2 norm, aka Euclidean length, of a regarded as a vector."""
    return sqrt(sum(v ** 2 for v in a.itervalues()))

def similarity(a, b):
    """Cosine similarity of a and b."""
    return dot(a, b) / (l2norm(a) * l2norm(b))
```

If all your weights/scores are non-negative, this returns a number between zero and one with one meaning a perfect match. You can read more about cosine similarity in any textbook on information retrieval, e.g. [Manning, Raghavan and Schütze](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/dot-products-1.html).

Comment: Thanks, that's really interesting!

Answer (score 1):

You should treat each of the tags as a dimension in vector space, and apply the [cosine similarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity).

For example:

```
import numpy as np

def cosine_similarity(dict1, dict2):
    sim = float(sum([dict1[k] * dict2[k] for k in intersect(dict1,dict2)]))
    return sim / (norm_values(dict1) * norm_values(dict2))

def norm_values(dict):
    v = np.array(dict.values())
    return np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(v)))

def intersect(dict1,dict2):
    return list(set(dict1.keys()) & set(dict2.keys()))

tags = {
    'grails': {
        'post-rock': 100,
        'instrumental': 53,
        'experimental': 38,
        'ambient': 30,
        'post rock': 14,
        'psychedelic': 11,
        'Psychedelic Rock': 6,
        'Progressive rock': 6,
        'rock': 4,
        'instrumental rock': 3,
        'atmospheric': 3,
        'american': 3,
        'space rock': 1
    },
    'camel': {
        'Progressive rock': 100,
        'classic rock': 28,
        'art rock': 24,
        'Progressive': 18,
        'rock': 17,
        'symphonic prog': 7,
        'british': 6,
        'Symphonic Rock': 4,
        'Canterbury Scene': 3,
        'prog rock': 3,
        'prog': 3,
        'Psychedelic Rock': 2,
        'space rock': 1
    },
    'mozart': {
        'Classical': 100,
        'mozart': 30,
        'instrumental': 21,
        'composers': 16,
        'opera': 13,
        'piano': 11,
        'Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart': 9,
        'symphonic': 9,
        'orchestral': 8,
        'austrian': 5
    }
}
query = {
    'Progressive rock': 100,
    'experimental': 33,
    'classic rock': 26,
    'Progressive': 23,
    'rock': 23,
    'art rock': 12,
    'psychedelic': 5,
    'prog rock': 5,
    'british': 5,
    'prog': 4,
    'Experimental Rock': 3,
    'Avant-Garde': 3,
    'Psychedelic Rock': 3,
    'Jazz Rock': 2
}

for t in tags:
    print "{}: {}".format(t, cosine_similarity(tags[t], query))
```

This produces:

```
mozart: 0.0
grails: 0.141356488829
camel: 0.944080602442
```